# Django: How to override 3rd party views by using DRY principle?

Tags: django, django-views

I have created a separate app for a feature I am planning to extend using this 3rd party app and I don't intend to touch its code.

The view I want to extend, posts a question or gets a form for a user to ask a question. 
I want to use this view to post an article. The form it uses is different.

Psuedo code below:

```
post_question_view(request)

    If user is authenticated and read only, redirect somewhere else.
    form = form.Askquestionform(request.REQUEST) ( I would like to do form = form.AskArticleform())

    If the request is post and form is valid, get clean data. (The article will include additional data)

    If user is authenticated, draft a question and write the question to the database. Generate a new-question-posted signal and redirect. (I don't have to make any changes here I guess)

    If user is not authenticated, create anonymous question, write it to the database and redirect to the login page. 

    If the request is get fill in the form intial and render to ask_question.html (I would like to render to ask_article.html)
```

Most of the code is there with minor altercations that needs to be done. I need to fill in few blanks and add some new blanks to the existing code.
How do I do this using the dry princliple?

1. Should I create a wrapper for the 2 functions and based on the request, call the appropriate one?
2. Is it possible to use a decorator? The form will contain new fields so without modifying the current view, I don't think its possible.
3. Or is there no other way than to copy this view to my app and make the modifications?

Comment: You should really post some real code example, as options may vary quite a bit depending on the 3rd party view implementation.

Comment: The view you are trying to depict here, is it written by you or the 3rd party app? With such ambiguous code its tough, could you get more close to the real scenario?

Comment: Do the source function (which you want to extend) has necessary formal parameters to pass what you want (e.g. different form)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer your three questions on the assumption based on your pseudocode that `post_question_view` is an old fashioned (not class-based) Django view with no parameters:

1. No, creating a wrapper that invokes one of the two views is not DRY, if the two views repeat the code. That's just hiding the repeated code behind the wrapper.
2. No, without the `post_question_view` having any parameters to modify its behavior, like using a different form, a decorator won't help.
3. No. The view isn't written in such a way to allow these modifications. On one had it doesn't have parameters that change its behavior in the ways you want -- if it did you could use these parameters. On the other hand it isn't a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) with its functionality organized into overridable fields and methods -- if it were you could subclass the view and override the appropriate fields and methods.

There is one exception to what I'm saying based on a technicality. You could use Python's `inspect` module to get the source code of the original view within your code at runtime, then literally modify the code on a textual level at runtime, then evaluate that code at runtime to create your new view. This would technically be DRY in the sense that you aren't repeating yourself in your source code, but it's not at all what folks mean by DRY, as it's a cute trick rather than using sound code organization and architecture to avoid source code duplication.